# How to fetch data from Exchange Online without using Azure AD

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, office365, exchange-server

I want to develop android application with Xamarin or Android Studio. I need to fetch data in my Office 365 Calendar but I don't want to use Azure AD. How can I access directly and fetch datas ? or Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. In order to access the Calendar object you'll need to authenticate either your app or the user. Since Office 365 uses Azure Active Directory to manage users and application there is no way to avoid authenticating against Azure AD.